# Select xml element value in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, namespaces, extract

I am trying to extract a value from an xml element, located in an XMLTYPE column in an Oracle Table. The xml element which I am trying to extract have a parent for which a namespace is defined. 
The xml looks something like:

```
<a>
  <b xmlns="urn:www.someSite.com/myModel">
    <c>my value</c>
  </b>
</a>
```

If I want to extract the content of the "a" element, its context is correctly returned:

```
SELECT Extract(myColumn, '/a') FROM myTable;
```

But for returning the content of the "c" element I didn't succeed to find any version to work. The following instructions does not work:

```
SELECT Extract(myColumn, '/a/b/c') FROM myTable;

SELECT Extract(myColumn, '/a/b/c', 'xmlns="urn:www.someSite.com/myModel"') FROM myTable;

SELECT Extract(myColumn, '/a/b/c', 'urn:www.someSite.com/myModel') FROM myTable;
```

Can anybody help me, with the extract statement that would work in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `a` element does not have the namespace, you can first extract its child elements without using namespaces in the function, and then extract the value from the `b` with the namespace:
Try:

```
select extract(extract(myColumn, 'a/*'),
               'b/c/text()',
               'xmlns=urn:www.someSite.com/myModel') 
  from myTable
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select a.*
from   XMLTABLE(
         XMLNAMESPACES('urn:www.someSite.com/myModel' AS "ns"),
         '/*'
         PASSING my.myColumn           
         COLUMNS
           val  VARCHAR2(2000)   PATH '/a/ns:b/ns:c'
       ) a, myTable my;
```

Comment: I will add that this is also the better modern solution now since extract/extractvalue are depreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When the default namespace changes, one way to specify namespaces is to write the wildcard character ('*') and the **local-name()** and **namespace-uri()** XPath functions.

`select extract(myColumn, '/a/*[local-name()='b' and namespace-uri()='urn:www.someSite.com/myModel']/*[local-name()='c' and namespace-uri()='urn:www.someSite.com/myModel']')
    from myTable`

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,ename||',')).EXTRACT('//text()') "Result"
FROM   emp
```