# Update xml element value in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, namespaces, updatexml

Having a XMLTYPE column in an Oracle table, I would like to update the values of some xml elements using UpdateXML method but I have troubles doing so because of a namespace which is applied on an xml element which is not parent. The xml structure of my elmenets looks something like:

```
<a>
  <b xmlns="urn:www.someSite.com/myModel">
    <c>my value</c>
  </b>
</a>
```

and an update of the following form it does not work:

```
UPDATE myTable 
  SET myColumn = UpdateXML(myColumn, '/a/b/c','other value', 'xmlns="urn:www.someSite.com/myModel"');
```

Comment: Can't you change the xml to have at least a shortname for the namespace ie `xmlns:ns1="urn:www.someSite.com/myModel"` so you could do `/a/ns1:b/ns1:c`

Comment: no, I cannot change the xml, this is the format in which is saved in the database, and it cannot be changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much the same as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975518/select-xml-element-value-in-oracle/9975958) but uglier...

```
UPDATE myTable
   SET myColumn = updatexml(myColumn ,
                 '/a/*',
                 updatexml(extract(myColumn , '/a/*'),
                           'b/c/text()',
                           'my new value',
                           'xmlns=urn:www.someSite.com/myModel'));
```

**EDIT:** If you have more then one `b` element in `a` you'll have to change the whole text within `a` and not for each child, so you can try:

```
UPDATE myTable
   SET myColumn = updatexml(myColumn ,
                 '/a/text()',
                 updatexml(extract(myColumn , '/a/*'),
                           'b/c/text()',
                           'my new value',
                           'xmlns=urn:www.someSite.com/myModel'));
```