# Loading the data into Netezza database using xquery from XML source

Tags: database, etl, xquery, netezza, xquery-sql

I have a source as XML and has a huge number of records. just for the sample I have pasted 1 record below :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/BCF-Termination-Details">
<wd:Report_Entry>
            <wd:Worker>
                    <wd:Associate_ID>997215</wd:Associate_ID>
                    <wd:Total_Base_Pay_Amount>13</wd:Total_Base_Pay_Amount>
                    <wd:Total_Base_Pay_Currency wd:Descriptor="USD"><wd:ID wd:type="WID">9e996ffdd3e14da0ba7275d5400bafd4</wd:ID><wd:ID wd:type="Currency_ID">USD</wd:ID><wd:ID wd:type="Currency_Numeric_Code">840</wd:ID></wd:Total_Base_Pay_Currency>
                    <wd:Length_of_Service_-_Position>0 year(s), 4 month(s), 7 day(s)</wd:Length_of_Service_-_Position>
            </wd:Worker>
            <wd:Time_Type wd:Descriptor="Part time"><wd:ID wd:type="WID">3baf0a7f595210daec53e26fa7476d5b</wd:ID><wd:ID wd:type="Position_Time_Type_ID">Part_time</wd:ID></wd:Time_Type>
            <wd:Hire_Date>2022-05-25-07:00</wd:Hire_Date>
            <wd:Termination_Date>2022-10-02-07:00</wd:Termination_Date>
            <wd:Date_Initiated>2022-10-28T17:39:53.943-07:00</wd:Date_Initiated>
            <wd:Termination_Category>Voluntary</wd:Termination_Category>
            <wd:Termination_Reason>Job Abandonment</wd:Termination_Reason>
            <wd:Length_of_Service_in_Days>130</wd:Length_of_Service_in_Days>
            <wd:workdayID>f415ada264f1100211408522a0e00000</wd:workdayID>
</wd:Report_Entry></wd:Report_Data>
```

I need this to implement in ETL. Using xml as source need few of the columns from the xml and load into the database. I am new to xquery, so need to know how can we start it. I am doing the POC on this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extract the values from xml source you can try using the XML functions from SQLEXT Toolkit package which can be installed on top of Netezza.

Here is an example of fetching the associate_id from the xml source. You can enter the extracted value in a table.

```
select xmlextractvalue(xmlparse(ele_string),'/Report_Entry/Worker/Associate_ID') as associate_id from (select replace(element,'wd:','') as ele_string from t1) as foo;

ASSOCIATE_ID
--------------
 997215
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer Nikita. I have a followup question on the same. Suppose I have a big XML file that contains the above information and I need to call that xml file in particular script using xml filename and using your query I need to load it into the table in Netezza database. How Do I do that? How do I declare/call the xml file in the script and load it?
I am new to Netezza, xquery so not have much idea on this.

Comment: Hi @ImSahil, Why do you need a script for this? Will it possible for you to load the xml data directly into a table (staging) and then create a final table as "create table final_table as select xmlextract....." by applying above mentioned functions on staging table?

Comment: I can do that but I am not getting how to proceed. You have written the query here but how the query knows about the xml file?

Comment: Oh ok. I inserted xml source in foo table the datatype I used was "varchar(<size>)". In case you want to insert multiple rows(xml data) in the table you can use nzload command from netezza.

Comment: Thanks for your help Nikita. One more doubt , From the XML above what if I need Total_Base_Pay_Currency as "USD" from CURRENCY_ID. Then How the query should look?

Comment: When I am using query "select 
xmlextractvalue(xmlparse(ele_string),'/Report_Entry/Worker/Total_Base_Pay_Currency')
as Total_Base_Pay_Currency 
from (select replace(XML_VALUE,'wd:','') as ele_string from foo) as t1;"
I am getting all the value like "9e996ffdd3e14da0ba7275d5400bafd4USD840"
I just need "USD" from this.

Comment: I am able to get the correct value of Total_Base_Pay_Currency by query but the real challaenge I am facing is I have XML which has around more than 200,000 characters. How do we store that in the table. Is there any way we can just give the xml file path & extract the value?

Comment: Because I am running the query for multiple xml rows I am getting this error "ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  0 : Single Row Query returns more than one row"

Comment: Ok. Let me check how we can avoid inserting values in a table.